# create and call method for buttons inside another method to modify

Tags: c#, object, button, methods

I'm fairly new to C# (and programming in general), so please try to be detailed if you can.  I tried to search for this but unable to find an answer.  I have a form with 10 buttons. On each button click, I'm going to do the same thing initially, such as start a progress bar and disable the button until the button methods have been completed.  Then I'll enable the button again and disable the progress bar.  So my question is, how can I create a general method that allows me to do the the same function for any variable method?  Example:

```
private void btnOne() {disableButton(); some statements here; enableButton()}
private void btnTwo() {disableButton(); some statements here; enableButton()}
private void btnThree() {disableButton(); some statements here; enableButton()}
private void btnFour() {disableButton(); some statements here; enableButton()}
private void disableButton()
{
  this.button.Enabled = false;
  progressBar.Visible = true;
}
private void enableButton()
{
  this.button.Enabled = true;
  progressBar.Visible = false;
}
```

So in the example above, I want to write one universal method that disables btnOne, btnTwo, btnThree, or btnFour, based on which one was clicked.  Same for re-enabling the button.

I know I can get it to work doing this but it doesn't look efficient since I'm rewriting the same code over and over:

```
private void btnOne() 
   {btnOne.Enabled = false; some statements here; btnOne.Enabled = true;}
private void btnTwo() 
   {btnTwo.Enabled = false; some statements here; btnTwo.Enabled = true;}
private void btnThree() 
   {btnThree.Enabled = false; some statements here; btnThree.Enabled = true;}
private void btnFour() 
   {bthFour.Enabled = false; some statements here; bthFour.Enabled = true;}
```

Comment: Is this all the same in each function? `some statements here;`

Comment: No, each button will perform different set of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just write a method that accepts a button:

```
private void DoTheButtonStuff(Button button)
{
    button.Enabled = false;
    progressBar.Visible = true;

    // Do stuff here

    button.Enabled = true;
    progressBar.Visible = false;
}
```

Keep in mind though, that unless you're performing the tasks on a separated thread, the button disable/enable and the progress bar updates won't actually be seen. The interface will, in essence, be frozen until the task is finished. You could run `Application.DoEvents()` to get the interface to update, but that introduces another set of problems.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't believe it was as simple as overloading using the object.  Now I have to do research on "threading" to get the UI to work properly w/o issues.

Comment: Check out my answer with a simple background worker. Using a combination of that and this answer you can come up with a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Here is the complete solution (for 2 buttons). You have to set the `Click` event for each button to be `btn_Click`

```
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        btn.Enabled = false;

        MyBackgroundWorker bgw = new MyBackgroundWorker(btn);

        if (btn == btnOne) {
            bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork_One;
        } else if (btn == btnTwo) {
            bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork_Two;
        }
        //...

        bgw.RunWorkerAsync(); // button enabled when completed
    }

    private void bgw_DoWork_One(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        // button 1 statements
    }
    private void bgw_DoWork_Two(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        // button 2 statements
    }

    public class MyBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker {

        protected Button btn;

        public MyBackgroundWorker(Button btn) : base() {
            this.btn = btn;
            this.btn.Enabled = false;
            this.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        }

        private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
            btn.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is pointless as the button is never disabled while the UI is pumping messages.

Comment: I know it's implied, but you might want to specify to the OP that then each button will subscribe to this handler for its Click event

Comment: There's no much point in providing an answer if you're just going to say that it doesn't work right afterwards...

Comment: @Servy I took the OPs question to be about buttons having the same handler, not about UI.

Comment: The handlers are *not* the same though; he simply wants all of the handlers to disable the button before doing whatever *button specific* code they have.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, depending on what `Some statements here` means.

If all the statements will be the same then you can do this:

```
public void HandleButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).Enabled = false;
    progressBar.Visible = true;

    //Some statements

    progressBar.Visible = false;
    (sender as Button).Enabled = true;
}
```

And, in your form, designate the click event of each button to go to that method.

If `Some statements here` is different for each button, you can do this:

```
private void btnOne(object sender, EventArgs e) //Do this for each button
{ 
    ChangeVisualState(sender as Button, false);
    //Statements
    ChangeVisualState(sender as Button, true);
}
public void ChangeVisualState(Button btn, bool buttonState)
{
    btn.Enabled = buttonState;
    progressBar.Visible = !buttonState;
}
```

Hopefully that helps

Comment: This is pointless as the button is never disabled while the UI is pumping messages.

Comment: Which part is pointless? I do this almost literally with every form I create in some way, shape, or form and have never run into issues.

Comment: The entire UI is frozen for the duration of the click handler.  The button is enabled again before it is ever disabled.  It doesn't "not work", but it also adds nothing at all over just omitting all of that code.  Even *without* this code it's impossible for the button to be clicked before the handler finishes running.

Comment: Yeah I guess he would have to break it out into separate threaded pieces in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the click events of each button.  The example below creates a single event handler for all buttons.

For more info on button click events, see [this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/button).

For simplicity, I would create a new event handler for each button.  That way, you can handle that button's specific progress bar.

```
btnOne.Click += new EventHandler(this.HandleButtonClick); 
btnTwo.Click += new EventHandler(this.HandleButtonClick); 
btnThree.Click += new EventHandler(this.HandleButtonClick);

protected void HandleButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    clickedButton.Enabled = false;
    ...
    clickedButton.Enabled = true; 
}
```

Comment: This is pointless as the button is never disabled while the UI is pumping messages.  It's also a duplicate of two other answers already posted here.

Comment: I don't think a discussion about multithreading would help the OP.  And I type slow.

Comment: Well first off, if he's performing a long running operation in the UI thread then yes, a discussion about threading is most certainly warranted.  Next, if for whatever unfortunate reason you decide *not* to do the work in another thread (which this answer is showing) the fact remains that there is no point whatsoever in adding this code.  It will function identically to simply omitting it, as it is impossible for the button to be clicked while the handler is running.

Comment: In reality, the OP has two problems.  He just hasn't gotten to the multithreading problem yet.  This post was designed to help him understand his first problem -- event handling.

Comment: This solves exactly none of his problems though.  You're *claiming* to solve a problem without actually solving it.

Answer (score 0):

For a WinForms app:

As has been mentioned, you'd want to do your work in a background thread. Doing it on the UI thread would 'freeze' the screen which will make the disabling/re-enabling invisible to the user.

To generalize the Enabling/disabling

```
private void isEnabled(Button btn, bool _bool)
{
    btn.Enabled = _bool;
}
```

You'll also need to create a separate method for making the progress bar visible/invisible. This will be used to make thread safe calls to the UI thread as explained below.

```
private void isVisible(bool _bool)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = _bool;
}
```

You would then want to make sure you run your tasks on a background thread. You can create a single click event handler as follows:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Sender is the button that was clicked
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(PerformTasks, sender);
}
```

Because you will be working with a background thread, you will need to create delegates to make thread safe calls back to the UI thread.

```
private delegate void ButtonDelegate(Button btn, bool isEnabled);
private delegate void ProgressBarDelegate(bool isVisible);
```

Finally, the work horse of your code. This method runs in the background and makes thread safe calls back to the UI thread when the job starts and completes.

```
private void PerformTasks(object obj)
{
    //The passed in obj is the sender, in our case the clicked button
    Button btn = obj as Button;
    ButtonDelegate delButton = new ButtonDelegate(isEnabled);
    ProgressBarDelegate delProgressBar = new ProgressBarDelegate(isVisible);

    //Make a thread safe call to disable button and make progressbar visible
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        btn.Invoke(delButton, btn, false);
        progressBar1.Invoke(delProgressBar, true);
    }
    else
    {
        btn.Enabled = false;
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
    }

    switch (btn.Name)
    {
        case "button1":
            //Code to run in background for button 1
            //alternatively, for organization/debugging purposes
            //create a sub method
            break;
        case "button2":
            //case 2
            break;
        //... more cases
    }

    //Make a thread safe call to re-enable button and make progress bar invisible
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        btn.Invoke(delButton, btn, true);
        progressBar1.Invoke(delProgressBar, false);
    }
    else
    {
        btn.Enabled = true;
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
    }

}
```

For more information on making thread safe calls in WinForms see the following [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28VS.80%29.aspx).